# Adding the Multiselect feature to an Angular4 dropdown?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

Currently I am using **angular4**. In **angular2** for multi-select drop-downs third party modules are available on `github` like [Angular2 Dropdown Multiselect](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect). For angular4 it is not available.
And I want to use same module with **angular4**. As per my knowledge, there is no difference between angular 2 and 4, but still it doesn't support my application. I am using reactive forms , it's throwing error like **this.validator is not a function** you can see my test case https://plnkr.co/edit/WSmoohuGZNFgfrJSGrqs?p=preview

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: what do you mean by `For angular4 it is not available.`? did you get any error in console?

Comment: yes , it's showing this.validator is not function

Comment: basically it will work. Did this error gone if you remove `Angular2 Dropdown Multiselect`?

Comment: yes , I am using reactive form , it's works fine, If I am  using above package I am getting error

Comment: I just made a simple plunker with this package. https://plnkr.co/edit/NyOJ0U42192rEZhtDP0k?p=preview

Comment: Can you please modify the plunker as per reactive forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143648/discussion-between-runali-and-pengyy).

Comment: Hope so this could help you https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown